# Python __new__ from child class

Tags: python, class, oop

I create class, that return results def instead of object of class

I have code:

```
class IProcessingQuery(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            instance = super().__new__(cls)
            return instance.get_normal_query(args[0])

    def get_normal_query(self, query_user: str):
        pass

class DictProcessingQuery(IProcessingQuery):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            cls.dict_to = args[1]
            instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            return instance.get_normal_query(args[0])

    def get_normal_query(self, query_user="") -> str:
        normal_query = query_user
        return manipuloffer.get_offer_with_dict(normal_query, self.__class__.dict_to)
```

This don't work, because first `__new__` return str.

How I fix it?

I tried call second `__new__` without `super()`, but it's don't work

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, provide code showing how you use things you defined, expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: return `instance` in the derived class. `get_normal_query` was already called in `super().__new__`. There's no point in calling it again.

Answer (score 0):

Matthias Huschle, thx.

I update this code

```
class DictProcessingQuery(IProcessingQuery):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            cls.dict_to = args[1]
            return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_normal_query(self, query_user="") -> str:
        normal_query = query_user
        return manipuloffer.get_offer_with_dict(normal_query, self.__class__.dict_to)
```